# MediaCodec Video Create Too Fast

Tags: android, android-camera, mediamuxer, android-mediacodec

I am trying to create Video frames camera frames using Camera1.Even when I take long Video from camera Video Plays it Too Fast.I tried changing bitrates and frame rates.
image byte[] from camera frames is being queued and fed to this class so that we could create video from bitmaps or byte[]
What we have done.

Opened up camera.Took camera frame from onNextFrame method using Camera1.We could have used MediaRecorder for Recording the video but simultaneous frame rendering to surfaceView and video recording using camera1 cannot be done.So we have used MediaCodec to create mp4 video from frames so that frame rendering and recording a video can be done.

```
package com.sukshi.smartid_demo;

import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
import android.graphics.Matrix;
import android.media.MediaCodec;
import android.media.MediaCodecInfo;
import android.media.MediaCodecList;
import android.media.MediaFormat;
import android.media.MediaMuxer;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Build;
import android.support.annotation.RequiresApi;
import android.util.Log;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.nio.ByteBuffer;
import java.util.Queue;
import java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentLinkedQueue;
import java.util.concurrent.CountDownLatch;

import static com.sukshi.smartid_demo.Camera.CameraSource.angle;

public class BitmapToVideoEncoder {
    private static final String TAG = BitmapToVideoEncoder.class.getSimpleName();

    private IBitmapToVideoEncoderCallback mCallback;
    private File mOutputFile;
    private Queue<Bitmap> mEncodeQueue = new ConcurrentLinkedQueue();
    private MediaCodec mediaCodec;
    private MediaMuxer mediaMuxer;

    private Object mFrameSync = new Object();
    private CountDownLatch mNewFrameLatch;

    private static final String MIME_TYPE = "video/avc"; // H.264 Advanced Video Coding
    private static int mWidth;
    private static int mHeight;
    private static final int BIT_RATE = 1000000;
    private static final int FRAME_RATE = 30; // Frames per second

    private static final int I_FRAME_INTERVAL = 1;

    private int mGenerateIndex = 0;
    private int mTrackIndex;
    private boolean mNoMoreFrames = false;
    private boolean mAbort = false;

    public interface IBitmapToVideoEncoderCallback {
        void onEncodingComplete(File outputFile);
    }

    public BitmapToVideoEncoder(IBitmapToVideoEncoderCallback callback) {
        mCallback = callback;
    }

    public boolean isEncodingStarted() {
        return (mediaCodec != null) && (mediaMuxer != null) && !mNoMoreFrames && !mAbort;
    }

    public int getActiveBitmaps() {
        return mEncodeQueue.size();
    }

    public void startEncoding(int width, int height, File outputFile) {
        mWidth = width;
        mHeight = height;
        mOutputFile = outputFile;

        String outputFileString;
        try {
            outputFileString = outputFile.getCanonicalPath();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.e(TAG, "Unable to get path for " + outputFile);
            return;
        }

        MediaCodecInfo codecInfo = selectCodec(MIME_TYPE);
        if (codecInfo == null) {
            Log.e(TAG, "Unable to find an appropriate codec for " + MIME_TYPE);
            return;
        }
        Log.d(TAG, "found codec: " + codecInfo.getName());
        int colorFormat;
        try {
            colorFormat = selectColorFormat(codecInfo, MIME_TYPE);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            colorFormat = MediaCodecInfo.CodecCapabilities.COLOR_FormatYUV420SemiPlanar;
        }

        try {
            mediaCodec = MediaCodec.createByCodecName(codecInfo.getName());
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.e(TAG, "Unable to create MediaCodec " + e.getMessage());
            return;
        }

        MediaFormat mediaFormat = MediaFormat.createVideoFormat(MIME_TYPE, mWidth, mHeight);
        mediaFormat.setInteger(MediaFormat.KEY_BIT_RATE, BIT_RATE);
        mediaFormat.setInteger(MediaFormat.KEY_FRAME_RATE, FRAME_RATE);
        mediaFormat.setInteger(MediaFormat.KEY_COLOR_FORMAT, colorFormat);
        mediaFormat.setInteger(MediaFormat.KEY_I_FRAME_INTERVAL, I_FRAME_INTERVAL);
        mediaCodec.configure(mediaFormat, null, null, MediaCodec.CONFIGURE_FLAG_ENCODE);
        mediaCodec.start();
        try {
            mediaMuxer = new MediaMuxer(outputFileString, MediaMuxer.OutputFormat.MUXER_OUTPUT_MPEG_4);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.e(TAG,"MediaMuxer creation failed. " + e.getMessage());
            return;
        }

        Log.d(TAG, "Initialization complete. Starting encoder...");

        new EncodingAsync().execute();
    }

    public void stopEncoding() {
        if (mediaCodec == null || mediaMuxer == null) {
            Log.d(TAG, "Failed to stop encoding since it never started");
            return;
        }
        Log.d(TAG, "Stopping encoding");

        mNoMoreFrames = true;

        synchronized (mFrameSync) {
            if ((mNewFrameLatch != null) && (mNewFrameLatch.getCount() > 0)) {
                mNewFrameLatch.countDown();
            }
        }
    }

    public void abortEncoding() {
        if (mediaCodec == null || mediaMuxer == null) {
            Log.d(TAG, "Failed to abort encoding since it never started");
            return;
        }
        Log.d(TAG, "Aborting encoding");

        mNoMoreFrames = true;
        mAbort = true;
        mEncodeQueue = new ConcurrentLinkedQueue(); // Drop all frames

        synchronized (mFrameSync) {
            if ((mNewFrameLatch != null) && (mNewFrameLatch.getCount() > 0)) {
                mNewFrameLatch.countDown();
            }
        }
    }

    public void queueFrame(byte[] nextData) {
        if (mediaCodec == null || mediaMuxer == null) {
            Log.d(TAG, "Failed to queue frame. Encoding not started");
            return;
        }

        Log.d(TAG, "Queueing frame");
        Bitmap OriginalBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(nextData, 0, nextData.length);

        Matrix matrix = new Matrix();
        matrix.postRotate(angle);
        Bitmap rotatedbitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(OriginalBitmap,0,0,OriginalBitmap.getWidth(),OriginalBitmap.getHeight(),matrix,true);

        mEncodeQueue.add(rotatedbitmap);

        synchronized (mFrameSync) {
            if ((mNewFrameLatch != null) && (mNewFrameLatch.getCount() > 0)) {
                mNewFrameLatch.countDown();
            }
        }
    }

    class EncodingAsync extends AsyncTask<Void,Void,File>{

        @RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP)
        @Override
        protected File doInBackground(Void... voids) {

            Log.d(TAG, "Encoder started");

            while(true) {
                if (mNoMoreFrames && (mEncodeQueue.size() ==  0)) break;

                Bitmap bitmap = mEncodeQueue.poll();
                if (bitmap ==  null) {
                    synchronized (mFrameSync) {
                        mNewFrameLatch = new CountDownLatch(1);
                    }

                    try {
                        mNewFrameLatch.await();
                    } catch (InterruptedException e) {}

                    bitmap = mEncodeQueue.poll();
                }

                if (bitmap == null) continue;

                byte[] byteConvertFrame = getNV21(bitmap.getWidth(), bitmap.getHeight(), bitmap);

                long TIMEOUT_USEC = 500000;
                int inputBufIndex = mediaCodec.dequeueInputBuffer(TIMEOUT_USEC);
                long ptsUsec = computePresentationTime(mGenerateIndex, FRAME_RATE);
                if (inputBufIndex >= 0) {
                    final ByteBuffer inputBuffer = mediaCodec.getInputBuffer(inputBufIndex);
                    inputBuffer.clear();
                    inputBuffer.put(byteConvertFrame);
                    mediaCodec.queueInputBuffer(inputBufIndex, 0, byteConvertFrame.length, ptsUsec, 0);
                    mGenerateIndex++;
                }
                MediaCodec.BufferInfo mBufferInfo = new MediaCodec.BufferInfo();
                int encoderStatus = mediaCodec.dequeueOutputBuffer(mBufferInfo, TIMEOUT_USEC);
                if (encoderStatus == MediaCodec.INFO_TRY_AGAIN_LATER) {
                    // no output available yet
                    Log.e(TAG, "No output from encoder available");
                } else if (encoderStatus == MediaCodec.INFO_OUTPUT_FORMAT_CHANGED) {
                    // not expected for an encoder
                    MediaFormat newFormat = mediaCodec.getOutputFormat();
                    mTrackIndex = mediaMuxer.addTrack(newFormat);
                    mediaMuxer.start();
                } else if (encoderStatus < 0) {
                    Log.e(TAG, "unexpected result from encoder.dequeueOutputBuffer: " + encoderStatus);
                } else if (mBufferInfo.size != 0) {
                    ByteBuffer encodedData = mediaCodec.getOutputBuffer(encoderStatus);
                    if (encodedData == null) {
                        Log.e(TAG, "encoderOutputBuffer " + encoderStatus + " was null");
                    } else {
                        encodedData.position(mBufferInfo.offset);
                        encodedData.limit(mBufferInfo.offset + mBufferInfo.size);
                        mediaMuxer.writeSampleData(mTrackIndex, encodedData, mBufferInfo);
                        mediaCodec.releaseOutputBuffer(encoderStatus, false);
                    }
                }
            }

            release();

            if (mAbort) {
                mOutputFile.delete();
                return null;
            } else {

                return mOutputFile;
            }

        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(File outputFile) {
            super.onPostExecute(outputFile);
            mCallback.onEncodingComplete(outputFile);
        }
    }


    private void release() {
        if (mediaCodec != null) {
            mediaCodec.stop();
            mediaCodec.release();
            mediaCodec = null;
            Log.d(TAG,"RELEASE CODEC");
        }
        if (mediaMuxer != null) {
            mediaMuxer.stop();
            mediaMuxer.release();
            mediaMuxer = null;
            Log.d(TAG,"RELEASE MUXER");
        }
    }

    private static MediaCodecInfo selectCodec(String mimeType) {
        int numCodecs = MediaCodecList.getCodecCount();
        for (int i = 0; i < numCodecs; i++) {
            MediaCodecInfo codecInfo = MediaCodecList.getCodecInfoAt(i);
            if (!codecInfo.isEncoder()) {
                continue;
            }
            String[] types = codecInfo.getSupportedTypes();
            for (int j = 0; j < types.length; j++) {
                if (types[j].equalsIgnoreCase(mimeType)) {
                    return codecInfo;
                }
            }
        }
        return null;
    }

    private static int selectColorFormat(MediaCodecInfo codecInfo,
                                         String mimeType) {
        MediaCodecInfo.CodecCapabilities capabilities = codecInfo
                .getCapabilitiesForType(mimeType);
        for (int i = 0; i < capabilities.colorFormats.length; i++) {
            int colorFormat = capabilities.colorFormats[i];
            if (isRecognizedFormat(colorFormat)) {
                return colorFormat;
            }
        }
        return 0; // not reached
    }

    private static boolean isRecognizedFormat(int colorFormat) {
        switch (colorFormat) {
            // these are the formats we know how to handle for
            case MediaCodecInfo.CodecCapabilities.COLOR_FormatYUV420Planar:
            case MediaCodecInfo.CodecCapabilities.COLOR_FormatYUV420PackedPlanar:
            case MediaCodecInfo.CodecCapabilities.COLOR_FormatYUV420SemiPlanar:
            case MediaCodecInfo.CodecCapabilities.COLOR_FormatYUV420PackedSemiPlanar:
            case MediaCodecInfo.CodecCapabilities.COLOR_TI_FormatYUV420PackedSemiPlanar:
                return true;
            default:
                return false;
        }
    }

    private byte[] getNV21(int inputWidth, int inputHeight, Bitmap scaled) {

        int[] argb = new int[inputWidth * inputHeight];

        scaled.getPixels(argb, 0, inputWidth, 0, 0, inputWidth, inputHeight);

        byte[] yuv = new byte[inputWidth * inputHeight * 3 / 2];
        encodeYUV420SP(yuv, argb, inputWidth, inputHeight);

        scaled.recycle();

        return yuv;
    }

    private void encodeYUV420SP(byte[] yuv420sp, int[] argb, int width, int height) {
        final int frameSize = width * height;

        int yIndex = 0;
        int uvIndex = frameSize;

        int a, R, G, B, Y, U, V;
        int index = 0;
        for (int j = 0; j < height; j++) {
            for (int i = 0; i < width; i++) {

                a = (argb[index] & 0xff000000) >> 24; // a is not used obviously
                R = (argb[index] & 0xff0000) >> 16;
                G = (argb[index] & 0xff00) >> 8;
                B = (argb[index] & 0xff) >> 0;


                Y = ((66 * R + 129 * G + 25 * B + 128) >> 8) + 16;
                U = ((-38 * R - 74 * G + 112 * B + 128) >> 8) + 128;
                V = ((112 * R - 94 * G - 18 * B + 128) >> 8) + 128;


                yuv420sp[yIndex++] = (byte) ((Y < 0) ? 0 : ((Y > 255) ? 255 : Y));
                if (j % 2 == 0 && index % 2 == 0) {
                    yuv420sp[uvIndex++] = (byte) ((U < 0) ? 0 : ((U > 255) ? 255 : U));
                    yuv420sp[uvIndex++] = (byte) ((V < 0) ? 0 : ((V > 255) ? 255 : V));

                }

                index++;
            }
        }
    }

    private long computePresentationTime(long frameIndex, int framerate) {
        return 132 + frameIndex * 1000000 / framerate;
    }
}
```

Comment: I think the problem is you are assuming that your video is 30 fps, but in fact preview frame that you got from camera may be less (video play too fast) or more (video play too slow) than that.

Answer (score 1):

You can see the main ways to use the [MediaCodec](https://bigflake.com/mediacodec/)

Generates a movie using OpenGL ES

https://bigflake.com/mediacodec/EncodeAndMuxTest.java.txt